# Pygame - Rotation of sprites not working after an event

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have been making a football game, where 2 cars try to hit a ball into a net. There are three things that make my car's rotation/angle incorrect, hitting a wall(sides or top and bottom), as soon as you start the game, the rotation starts off backwards, and when a goal is scored, the car continues at whatever the angle it was left off at before the goal goes in, despite resetting redangle. My code is below, I hope someone can fix it.

```
import pygame
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2
import time
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()
WIDTH = 1150
HEIGHT = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket League")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
bgimg = pygame.image.load("Football_pitch.png")
REDGOAL = pg.Surface((50, 150), pg.SRCALPHA)
REDGOAL.fill((255, 0, 0))
redgoal_rect = REDGOAL.get_rect(topleft=(0, 340))
redgoal_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(REDGOAL)
BLUEGOAL = pg.Surface((50, 150), pg.SRCALPHA)
BLUEGOAL.fill((0, 0, 255))
bluegoal_rect = REDGOAL.get_rect(topleft=(1100, 340))
bluegoal_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(REDGOAL)
BLUECAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, (0, 0, 255), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50,10), (0, 0)])
bluecar = BLUECAR_ORIGINAL
REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL
redspeed = 5
bluespeed = 5
ball_x = 575
ball_y = 400
dx = 0
dy = 0
x = 800
y = 500
redscore = 0
bluescore = 0
BALL = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(BALL, [0,0,0], [15, 15], 15)
ball_pos = Vector2(ball_x, ball_y)
ballrect = BALL.get_rect(center=ball_pos)
ball_vel = Vector2(dx, dy)
ball_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(BALL)
pos_red = Vector2(x,y)
vel_red = Vector2(redspeed,0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
redangle = 180
mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
mask_ball = pygame.mask.from_surface(BALL)
ballrect = BALL.get_rect(center=ball_pos)
vel_red.rotate_ip(-180)

def redgoal():
        ball_vel.x = 0
        ball_vel.y = 0
        ball_pos.x = 575
        ball_pos.y = 400
        vel_red.x = redspeed
        vel_red.y = 0
        pos_red.x = 800
        pos_red.y = 370
        redangle = 180
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-180)   

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if y <0:
        y = 10
    if y > 450:
        y = 440
    if x > 480:
        x = 470

    if ballrect.top < 0 and ball_vel.y < 0:
        ball_vel.y *= -1
    elif ballrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and ball_vel.y > 0:
        ball_vel.y *= -1
    if ballrect.left < 0 and ball_vel.x < 0:
        ball_vel.x *= -1
    elif ballrect.right > screen.get_width() and ball_vel.x > 0:
        ball_vel.x *= -1

    if redrect.top < 0 and vel_red.y < 0:
        vel_red.y *= -1
        redangle == 0
    elif redrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and vel_red.y > 0:
        vel_red.y *= -1
        redangle == 0
    if redrect.left < 0 and vel_red.x < 0:
        vel_red.x *= -1
        redangle == 0
    elif redrect.right > screen.get_width() and vel_red.x > 0:
        vel_red.x *= -1
        redangle == 0   

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        vel_red.scale_to_length(10)

    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red
    ball_vel *= .97  
    ball_pos += ball_vel
    ballrect.center = ball_pos

    offset_red = redrect[0] - ballrect[0], redrect[1] - ballrect[1]
    overlap_red = mask_ball.overlap(mask_red, offset_red)

    offset = redgoal_rect[0] - ballrect[0], redgoal_rect[1] - ballrect[1]
    redgoaloverlap = ball_mask.overlap(redgoal_mask, offset)

    if redgoaloverlap:
        redgoal()

    elif overlap_red:  
        ball_vel = Vector2(vel_red) * 1.4

    screen.blit(bgimg,(0,0))
    screen.blit(BALL, ballrect)
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    screen.blit(REDGOAL, redgoal_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We can not help you if we don't not what is happening in the rest of the program.

Comment: Why do you sometimes use the equal operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`)? These lines are pointless and can be removed.

Comment: Please create a version of your game that only contains one car and the code that's necessary to reproduce the problem. The example should still be complete and runnable, so that we don't have to add code.

Comment: I've edited it to as much of a  minimum length of code as possible

Comment: Should the cars bounce when they hit the border or should they just be stopped or slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to slide along the borders instead of bouncing, you can set the rect's `top`, etc. attributes to the border coords when it leaves the screen and then set the `pos_red` vector to the `rect.center` coords. The velocity will be unaffected.

To change the initial rotation of the car image, you need to `pg.transform.rotate` with the desired angle: `redcar = pg.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)`.

And the x component of the vel_red vector should be negative (point to the left) at the program start: `vel_red = Vector2(-redspeed, 0)`.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1150, 800))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pg.Surface((50, 30), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
redangle = 180
# Rotate the image/surface before the game starts.
redcar = pg.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
redspeed = 5
pos_red = Vector2(800, 500)
# -redspeed means the vector points to the left.
vel_red = Vector2(-redspeed, 0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
mask_red = pg.mask.from_surface(redcar)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_r:
                # Reset the car to the start position.
                redangle = 180
                redcar = pg.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
                pos_red = Vector2(800, 500)
                vel_red = Vector2(-redspeed, 0)
                redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
                mask_red = pg.mask.from_surface(redcar)

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pg.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pg.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pg.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pg.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pg.K_UP]:
        vel_red.scale_to_length(10)

    # Move the car.
    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red

    # Slide at the borders.
    if redrect.top < 0 and vel_red.y < 0:
        redrect.top = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and vel_red.y > 0:
        redrect.bottom = screen.get_height()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    if redrect.left < 0 and vel_red.x < 0:
        redrect.left = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.right > screen.get_width() and vel_red.x > 0:
        redrect.right = screen.get_width()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)

    # Blit everything.
    screen.fill((30, 110, 30))
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    rec = pg.Rect(800, 500, 50, 30)
    rec.center = (800, 500)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (90, 20, 20), rec, 1)  # Start position.
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Ok thanks, the sliding works like a treat, but have you got an idea of how to make the car face the left hand side at the start / after a goal, pygame.transform.rotate still make the car's centre of movement different every time

Comment: The car faces the right way, however the angle of rotation is wrong

Comment: You have to reset the velocity vector, the position vector, the rect, the angle and the image.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm not sure how to make the car rotate after the goal. I've tried the same method as how it would work upon starting the program, but it doesn't work, and I've spent 30-60 minutes trying to fix it, but still can't figure it(probably because I'm being stupid). Got any ideas?

Comment: You just have to do the same as in the lines 12-20 of my example. I've edited the answer to show you how (press "R" to reset the car). Also, the image should be rotated before the rect is created.

Comment: Ok, so it works now, keydown "r" is the event, just like redgoal() is in my code. Thanks very much